# Integrating Semantic-UI "Dist" folder into Firebase Deploy after Grunt Build

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, firebase, semantic-ui

I have a firebase-hosted app that is working, and now I'm trying to integrate Semantic-UI so that when I deploy it to firebase it will have all the Semantic icons and styles.  The icons and styles are not making it over somehow, and they show up just fine on my local "grunt serve."

I have semantic.js referenced and integrated into vendor.js, and I have semantic.css referenced in the header and integrated into the vendor.css during the build.  It seems I'm overthinking how to get my icons and styles up on firebase.  Thoughts?

My dist folder for my grunt build is in [root folder]/dist and the dist folder for Semantic-UI is in [root folder]/bower_components/semantic-ui/dist.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="devNews">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

      <div ng-include="'views/nav.html'"></div>
      <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
       (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
       m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
       })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/firebase-simple-login/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/mockfirebase/dist/mockfirebase.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/posts.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/post.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/authorization.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/profile.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/profile.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/postview.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/nav.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/authorization.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/filters/url.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to first add the following to my Gruntfile.js.  Since I'm not using Bootstrap any longer, I just replaced it with some Semantic-UI directory settings:

```
copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/semantic-ui/dist',
          src: 'themes/**/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/semantic-ui/dist',
          src: 'components/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },
```

Then I had to reference the CDN for my icons, adding them to my semantic.css.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.2/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.eot");
    }
```

etc. for each icon type.